# Advanced filtering of array of objects and nested objects based on multiple conditions in nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, filter, javascript-objects

I have an array of complex objects, I want to filter them based on multiple criteria and if possible maybe extract some values on the way at the same time. I was thinking about having a function:
`extractValues(array, filters, toExtract)` where toExtract is the property of which values I want to extract.

Here is a sample data:

```
const accounts  = [
  {
    "role": "admin1",
    "adminCapabilities": [
      {
        "name": "Test-Name-1",
        "admingFlags": ["flag1.1", "flag1.2"],
        "rightsFlags": [""],
        "otherFlags": ["C", "O"],
        "types": ["Type1.1", "Type1.2"]
      },
      {
        "name": "Test-Name-2",
        "admingFlags": ["flag2.1", "flag2.2"],
        "rightsFlags": [""],
        "otherFlags": ["C", "O"],
        "types": ["Type2.1", "Type2.2"]
      }
    ],
    "accounts": [
      {
        "fase": "",
        "clients": ["C1", "C2", "C3"],
        "strat": ["S1", "", "S2"]
      },
      {
        "fase": "F1",
        "clients": ["F1C1", "F2C2", "F3C3"],
        "strat": ["F1S1", "", "F1S2"]
      }
    ],
    "extra": {
      "sides": ["SID", "SIT", "SMN"],
      "allow": true,
      "class": ["CLASS1", "CLASS2"]
    }
  },
  {
    "role": "admin2",
    "adminCapabilities": [
      {
        "name": "Test-Name-3",
        "admingFlags": ["flag2.1", "flag2.2"],
        "rightsFlags": [""],
        "otherFlags": ["C", "O"],
        "types": ["Type2.2", "Type2.2"]
      },
    ],
    "accounts": [
      {
        "fase": "",
        "clients": ["C1", "C2", "C3"],
        "strat": ["S1", "", "S2"]
      },
      {
        "fase": "F1",
        "clients": ["F1C1", "F2C2", "F3C3"],
        "strat": ["F1S1", "", "F1S2"]
      }
    ],
    "extra": {
      "sides": ["SMN"],
      "allow": false,
      "class": ["CLASS1", "CLASS2"]
    }
  }
]
```

And let's say I want to filter them out based on some filters:

```
const filters = {
  "strat": "S1",
  "clients": "C2",
  "sides": "SMN"
  // and maybe even more
};
extractValues(accounts, filters, "name");
const expectedResult = ["Test-Name-1", "Test-Name-2", "Test-Name-3"];
```

The final expected would be to extract some date, like if I want to extract the `name`, the expected result would be: `["Test-Name-1", "Test-Name-2", "Test-Name-3"]`

Another example:

```
const filters = {
  "role": "admin1"
  "strat": "S1",
  "clients": "C2",
  "sides": "SMN"
  // and maybe even more
};
extractValues(accounts, filters, "name");
const expectedResult = ["Test-Name-1", "Test-Name-2"];
```

Another example with empty strings with 2 different scenarios:

```
const filters = {
  "role": "", // accept anything on role
  "name": "Test-Name-1",
  "rightsFlags": "" // looking for righsFlags with value === ""
};
extractValues(accounts, filters, "admingFlags ");
const expectedResult = ["flag1.1", "flag1.2"],
```

So basically, filter by anything (even all of them but not the one we are looking for), and on the filtered data extract the desired values if it is not possible to extract them on the way.

I have tried firstly only to filter without extracting:

```
function filterArray(array, filters) {
  const filterKeys = Object.keys(filters);
  return array.filter(item => {
    // validates all filter criteria
    return filterKeys.every(key => {
      // ignores non-function predicates
      if (typeof filters[key] !== 'function') return true;
      return filters[key](item[key]);
    });
  });
}
```

But this is not actually working at all on those nested objects, and nested arrays of objects inside of it.

I have tried to convert my data to a dictionary thinking that will make things faster and easier but actually made them even harder for me. Converted to dictionary:

```
const accounts = {
  "admin1": {
    "adminCapabilities": {
      "Test-Name-1": {
        "admingFlags": ["flag1.1", "flag1.2"],
        "rightsFlags": [""],
        "otherFlags": ["C", "O"],
        "types": ["Type1.1", "Type1.2"]
      },
      "Test-Name-2": {
        "admingFlags": ["flag2.1", "flag2.2"],
        "rightsFlags": [""],
        "otherFlags": ["C", "O"],
        "types": ["Type2.1", "Type2.2"]
      },
    }
    "accounts": {
      "": {
        "clients": ["C1", "C2", "C3"],
        "strat": ["S1", "", "S2"]
      },
      "F1": {
        "clients": ["F1C1", "F2C2", "F3C3"],
        "strat": ["F1S1", "", "F1S2"]
      }
    }
    "extra": {
      "sides": ["SID", "SIT", "SMN"],
      "allow": true,
      "class": ["CLASS1", "CLASS2"]
    }
  },
  "admin2": {
    "adminCapabilities": {
      "Test-Name-2": {
        "admingFlags": ["flag2.1", "flag2.2"],
        "rightsFlags": [""],
        "otherFlags": ["C", "O"],
        "types": ["Type2.2", "Type2.2"]
      }
    },
    "accounts": {
      "": {
        "clients": ["C1", "C2", "C3"],
        "strat": ["S1", "", "S2"]
      },
      "F1": {
        "clients": ["F1C1", "F2C2", "F3C3"],
        "strat": ["F1S1", "", "F1S2"]
      }
    },
    "extra": {
      "sides": ["SMN"],
      "allow": false,
      "class": ["CLASS1", "CLASS2"]
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: You would need to define your filter critera more precisely. How should one know that e.g. `clients` is nested in `accounts` etc.

Comment: btw, `strat` vs `start` in properties? what s right? and why not use the complete access path to the property to check against?

Comment: just another probkem ho do you know if an empty string is a joker or data to search for? maybe omit joker at all and omit this property for filtering or use a different approach, like a symbol or a string with star, if not used as data.

Comment: @NinaScholz thanks, it was a typo, it is actually strat. The second one I was not sure how to do that as well highlight a difference between match empty and allow anything

Comment: what filter structure do you like to address nested properties?

Comment: the last wanted result works on a subset of the object. this makes the code worse, because of the decision which part of nested objct should go into the result set.

Comment: I could maybe change to be be like `undefined` value for when it can accept anything. Now I am trying to adapt your solution to the dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is approach to solve with properties, despite their nested position in objects or arrays.

It returns the wanted property of the outer object. The third example returns a wron result, because it can not differ the nested sub object.

To use a wildcard, just remove the property from filter. An empty string looks for an empty string.

```js
const
    extractValues = (data, filter, property) => {
         const
             getP = o => o && typeof o === 'object'
                 ? property in o
                     ? o[property]
                     : Object.values(o).flatMap(getP)
                 : [];

         return data
            .filter(item => Object
                .entries(filter)
                .every(([k, v]) => {
                     const
                        check = o => o && typeof o === 'object'
                            ? Array.isArray(o)
                                ? o.some(check)
                                : k in o
                                    ? o[k] === v || Array.isArray(o[k]) && o[k].includes(v)
                                    : Object.values(o).some(check)
                            : false;
                    return check(item);
                }))
            .flatMap(getP);
    },
    accounts = [{ role: "admin1", adminCapabilities: [{ name: "Test-Name-1", adminFlags: ["flag1.1", "flag1.2"], rightsFlags: [""], otherFlags: ["C", "O"], types: ["Type1.1", "Type1.2"] }, { name: "Test-Name-2", adminFlags: ["flag2.1", "flag2.2"], rightsFlags: [""], otherFlags: ["C", "O"], types: ["Type2.1", "Type2.2"] }], accounts: [{ fase: "", clients: ["C1", "C2", "C3"], strat: ["S1", "", "S2"] }, { fase: "F1", clients: ["F1C1", "F2C2", "F3C3"], strat: ["F1S1", "", "F1S2"] }], extra: { sides: ["SID", "SIT", "SMN"], allow: true, class: ["CLASS1", "CLASS2"] } }, { role: "admin2", adminCapabilities: [{ name: "Test-Name-3", adminFlags: ["flag2.1", "flag2.2"], rightsFlags: [""], otherFlags: ["C", "O"], types: ["Type2.2", "Type2.2"] }], accounts: [{ fase: "", clients: ["C1", "C2", "C3"], strat: ["S1", "", "S2"] }, { fase: "F1", clients: ["F1C1", "F2C2", "F3C3"], strat: ["F1S1", "", "F1S2"] }], extra: { sides: ["SMN"], allow: false, class: ["CLASS1", "CLASS2"] } }];

//console.log(extractValues(accounts, { strat: "S1", clients: "C2", sides: "SMN" }, "name"));
// ["Test-Name-1", "Test-Name-2", "Test-Name-3"];

//console.log(extractValues(accounts, { role: "admin1", strat: "S1", clients: "C2", sides: "SMN" }, "name"));
// ["Test-Name-1", "Test-Name-2"]

console.log(extractValues(accounts, { /* role: "", */ name: "Test-Name-1", rightsFlags: "" }, "adminFlags"));
// ["flag1.1", "flag1.2"]
// it returns all items, not only the ones from name: "Test-Name-1"
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Great solution, I really appreciate it but it is possible to adapt this solution to the data converted to dictionary? I am trying to learn about data structures and precessing of it and I am trying to adapt your solution to the second data format I gave in the description where it is as a dictionary.

Comment: with a dictionary, you need to get the entries as well for checking the nested properties. for me, an array is more handy than an object structure.

Comment: Testing on this: extractValues(accounts, {types: "Type1.1"}, "name") gives the wrong result. Should have returned ["Test-Name-1"] but it returns "[Test-Name-1", "Test-Name-2"]

Comment: yes, that is the problem which i described in the answer. actually it is not possible to distinguish between sub objects. and i have no idea how to solve it.